# Beautiful Soup scrape text from second child in same div class

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have two `<tr>` tags within the same div class. The first tr tag prints the text just fine. I am trying to access the second tr tag within the container that I have but I cant seem to get it to work. Also please note, not all containers have a second `<tr>` tag so I need an `if` statement to check if it exists first. Then if it does, print the text from it. Thanks!

```
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

containers = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"right"})

for container in containers:
    print(container.span.text)
    print(container.tr.text)

    if container.nextSiblings('tr')[1]:
        print(container.nextSiblings('tr')[1].text)
```

Comment: Have a look at this: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-next-siblings-and-find-next-sibling This might help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can locate all the `tr` elements within a container and check how many of them you have:

```
for container in containers:
    trs = container("tr")  # same as container.find_all("tr")

    if len(trs) > 1:
         print(trs[1].get_text())
```

---

You can also directly locate the second `tr` within every container in a single [CSS selector](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
for tr in soup.select(".right > tr:nth-of-type(2)"):
    print(tr.get_text())
```

Demo:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


data = """
<body>
    <div class="right">
        <tr>container 1 row 1</tr>
        <tr>container 1 row 2</tr>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <tr>container 2 row 1</tr>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <tr>container 3 row 1</tr>
        <tr>container 3 row 2</tr>
        <tr>container 3 row 3</tr>
    </div>
</body>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
for tr in soup.select(".right > tr:nth-of-type(2)"):
    print(tr.get_text())
```

would print:

```
container 1 row 2
container 3 row 2
```

Comment: great it worked! btw, just wondering why some of your syntax is different then mine? for example your .find_all compared to my .findAll? is that because your using python 2.7? sorry, im new to python

Comment: @itschrisho nono, `findAll()` is just a "legacy" BeautifulSoup version 3 style which is deprecated at this point. Thanks.